# Link to an element on the same page and have it centered in window

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, center, centering

I am working on a page and it is a little lengthy, so I chose to link to sections of it using the method below:

```
<a href="#myID">Link</a>

<div id="myID">Content that I would like in center of screen, rather than at the absolute top.</div>
```

Everything works correctly, as I am pretty proficient with basic stuff like this, but I am wondering if there is a way to make it so that the content I am linking to is a little farther from the top of the browser window, rather than immediately at the top.  It doesn't have to be perfectly centered, maybe a margin of 100px or so would be fine.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, that is a valid way to do it.

Comment: Not sure you understand my question...I know I am linking to the element correctly.  I am asking if there is a way to move the content more towards the center of the screen, when it appears after clicking the link.  I don't like having it all the way at the top of the window.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Diodeus understands, and was replying to your comment about using margins to do what you want.

Comment: No.  I don't want a margin on the element itself.  The page looks just fine.  I am linking to elements within the same page and when doing that the element I jump to is placed at the very top of the screen.  I am not trying to move the element in relation to anything within the page itself.  I am wondering if there is a way to make it so that when you link to items on the same page, they are not placed directly at the top of the screen, but rather have the page scrolled slightly so they are a little more towards center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
<script>

function change()
{
document.getElementById("myID").style.marginTop="100px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#myID" onclick="change()">Link</a>

<div id="myID">Content that I would like in center of screen, rather than at the absolute top.sss
<pre>
s
s
s
s
s
s</pre>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think it would be a hassle to do this for every ID I have, so I am just going to leave it.  It's not something that annoys me too much so I'll leave it as it.  Thank you for the help, though

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a little CSS:

```
#myID {
   margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Hope that helps!